# I got infinite loop while practicing array in C++ to find reversed number

Tags: c++, arrays

Hye, Im a beginner trying to learn C++ language. This is my code that I tried to find reverse input numbers using array. Can help me point my mistakes since I always got infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
const int ARRAY_SIZE=50;
int size[ARRAY_SIZE];
unsigned short int i;



cout << "You may enter up to 50 integers:\n";
cout << "\nHow many would you like to enter?  ";
cin >> size[ARRAY_SIZE];

cout << "Enter your number: \n";

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    cin >> size[i]; 
}

cout << "\nYour numbers reversed are:\n";

for (i = size[ARRAY_SIZE] - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    cout << " size[i]" << " ";

}
```

Comment: `cin >> size[ARRAY_SIZE];` writes off the end of the array. Everything after that is undefined behaviour. This is not writing to the "array size property" of the array. This is writing to the array at index `ARRAY_SIZE`, but only `0`..`ARRAY_SIZE-1` exists.

Comment: Tip: Since you're using C++, *use* C++. `std::vector<int> array` and then `int v; cin >> v ` is an easy way to capture single integers, then `array.push_back(v)` to add to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your infinite loop is because `i` is unsigned, so `i >= 0` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++-ified version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::cout << "You may enter up to 50 integers:\n";
  std::cout << "\nHow many would you like to enter?  ";

  int count;
  std::cin >> count;

  // Use a std::vector which can be extended easily
  std::vector<int> numbers;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Enter your number: \n";

    int v;
    std::cin >> v;

    // Add this number to the list
    numbers.push_back(v);
  }

  std::cout << "\nYour numbers reversed are:\n";

  // Use a reverse iterator to iterate through the list backwards
  for (auto i = numbers.rbegin(); i != numbers.rend(); ++i) {
    // An iterator needs to be de-referenced with * to yield the value
    std::cout << *i << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

There's many problems in your original code, but the clincher is this:

```cpp
for (i = size[ARRAY_SIZE] - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    cout << " size[i]" << " ";

}
```

Since you keep *adding* to `i` through each cycle you'll never go below zero, especially not for an `unsigned short int`. This should be:

```cpp
for (int i = count - 1; i > 0; --i) {
   std::cout << numbers[i];
}
```

Presuming you have a thing called `numbers` instead of the bizarrely named `size` and the array size is `count`, not `i`, as `i` is generally reserved for iterators and loop indexes.